# Save raw RBG values to JPG using libjpeg

Tags: c++, c++11, jpeg, libjpeg

I have a canvas that is represented by a 2D array of the type colorData

The class colorData simply holds the RGB value or each pixel.

I have been looking at examples of people using libjpeg to write a jpg but none of them seem to use the RGB values.

Is there a way to save raw RGB values to a jpeg using libjpeg? Or better yet, is there an example of code using the raw RGB data for the jpeg data?

Comment: Do you really need libjpeg, or can you accept OpenCV example?

Comment: Libjpeg is required for the assignment

Answer (score 1):

Look in `example.c` in the libjpeg source. It gives a complete example of how to write a JPEG file using RGB data.

The example uses a buffer variable `image_buffer` and height and width variables `image_width` and `image_height`. You will need to adapt it to copy the RGB values from your ColorData class and place them into the image buffer (this can be done one row at a time).

Fill an array of bytes with the RGB data (3 bytes for each pixel) and then set `row_buffer[0]` point to the array before calling `jpeg_write_scanlines`.

Comment: So for a pure red pixel I would push 25500 to the buffer?

Comment: You would push one byte with value 255, then one byte with 0 then one byte with 0.